# Checking If Table Is Exist By Using Specific Word From Table's Name In Sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to make my program checks if the table name is exist or not by searching letters or words from the table name... for example my tables name are (samAmerica) and (samGermany) I want the program to checks if there is any table name include (sam) word alone.. so when I search using sam word he will show me both tables... I know how to make it check it all but it is not helpful for me because I will be having a lot of same names but different nicknames as a tables.

this is my code where checks all the table name together.. I would appreciate if someone helps me.

```
public boolean istableNameexist(String un){
    boolean uexist = false;
    Connection con = myConnection.getconnection();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM  information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME  = ?");
        ps.setString(1,name.getText()+faturanumarasi.getText());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()){
            uexist = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("wrong");
    }

    return uexist;
}
```

Comment: Use like instead of =.

Comment: exec the query
SELECT * FROM  information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<string passed as un>'

and see whether that works. 

If there is no results, check what is suggested by Shadow (above) - 
ie. use Like

Comment: I tried it like you said but I am getting error

Comment: @Srinika I tried this too its showing me a lot of table in information_schema.tables but not mines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using  like operator

```
SELECT * FROM  information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE concat('%',?,'%')
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: it is finding it when I use all the word (samamerica) but it is not finding anythink when I use the word (sam)

Comment: SELECT * FROM  information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME  LIKE 'samamerica' this works but sam alone not working

Comment: did you try:

SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%sam%'

Comment: Yes I did and it didnt work then I tried SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'sam%' ....  like its checking the first letters from the word and it worked out

Comment: @abdullahaffoura  I have update the answer  with proper like  ..  anyway as you can see  in the doc link the pattern concat('%',?,'%')   or concat('%','sam','%') should work  .. so if this query fail check better for real param string  or column value content o